# If one bean is managed by Spring does this mean all created beans also have to be managed

Tags: java, spring

If I have a Spring bean that contains another non Spring bean like so :

```
@Component
class SpringBean {

  private MyBean mb = new MyBean();
}
```

I receive error : unable to wire bean MyBean

But if I declare the Bean within a method :

```
@Component
class SpringBean {

  private void myMethod(){
    MyBean mb = new MyBean();
  }
}
```

Then the bean is initialized correctly when the bean is called.

So does Spring not allow non Spring beans to be created by Spring beans ? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that the code you are showing does not has the behavior you are describing.

Comment: No, you should be able to use it like in the first one. There must be something else you are missing. Post the exception stacktrace and then we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only beans created by the Spring container will be managed by Spring and provide dependency injection and all the benefits (and problems) that Spring gives you.

> So does Spring not allow non Spring beans to be created by Spring beans ?

Spring beans are POJOs after all, so they can be manually created like any class with a public constructor. This means, you can do:

```
public void foo() {
    SpringBean springBeanNotManagedBySpring = new SpringBean();
   //use springBeanNotManagedBySpring...
}
```

But, as stated at the beginning of my answer, `springBeanNotManagedBySpring` is not managed by Spring, so it won't have the benefits of a Spring managed bean.

Note that you're doing two different things in your example:

- In the first code, you have a field in the class of type `MyBean` and Spring tries to inject it but looks like doesn't find a Spring bean to inject. You should post the configuration of your bean in order for us to do a better analysis on this.
- In the second code, you're creating a local variable (completely different from a field in class) of type `MyBean`, where the instantiation is up to the programmer.

Comment: OP, the distinction  you should start making is that an instance whose lifecycle is managed by Spring is called a bean. An instance that isn't is just an instance.